# Java equivalent of javascript method.apply(context,args)

Tags: java

I want to create static method to reuse example from android docs:

```
private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
            try {
                return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
            }
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        }
    }
```

Passing all arguments from doInBackground into downloadUrl.
How to do it in Java?

Thank you.

Comment: Pass `urls`? Without knowing what `downloadUrl` takes as its parameter, we're guessing. The general answer is that there's no equivalent, although you can use reflection to do a lot of things you probably shouldn't.

Comment: How you want to use it.

Comment: Why downloadUrl should know? O_o

Comment: Oh well, i guess i'll have to create it via Hash map. Why Java is so limited... It's so uncomfortable...

Answer (score 0):

There's no equivalent to `apply()` in Java.

You can pass infinitive numbers of params as array.
Declare your method as follow:

```
void method(String [] urls){
}
```

and call it:

```
object.method(new String [] {"arg1", "arg2"});
```

or better way:

```
void method2(String ...urls){
}
```

and you can simple call it like:

```
object.method2("arg1");
object.method2("arg1", "arg2");
object.method2("arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
```

it works, because in fact, compiler will change above expressions to:

```
object.method2(new String [] {"arg1"});
object.method2(new String [] {"arg1", "arg2"});
object.method2(new String [] {"arg1", "arg2", "arg3"});
```

Answer (score 0):

lambda expressions might help you..
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html